# jest не видит компоненты библиотеки Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, юнит-тесты, vuetify, jest

Я новичок в модульном тестирование, для начала решил покрыть все компоненты snapshot тестами. Все настроил и казалось бы все хорошо, но когда выполняю команду npm run unit появляется предупреждение [image: ошибка]

Сами тесты проходят, но мне кажется что из-за этого предупреждения некорректно сохраняются снапшоты 
Вот код теста

```js
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Button from '../../components/button.vue'
test('renders correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Button);
    expect(wrapper.element).toMatchSnapshot()

})
```

Как мне подружить jest c Vuetify? помогите... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Jest есть возможность [указать setup-скрипт](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array), который выполнится перед прогоном тестов. Сделайте в этом файле примерно следующее (псевдокод):

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
Vue.use(Vuetify);
```

Должно помочь.

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек, помогло )

Comment: Не сомневался ))